# ISO Week Number - M script

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I used below query in Power Query to create an ISO Week number:

`#"Inserted ISO Week Number" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted End of Week", "ISO Week Number", each if Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear([Date])-(Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7)=0 then  Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear(#date(Date.Year([Date])-1,12,31))-(Date.DayOfWeek(#date(Date.Year([Date])-1,12,31), Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7) else if (Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear([Date])-(Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7)=53 and (Date.DayOfWeek(#date(Date.Year([Date]),12,31), Day.Monday)+1<4)) then 1 else  Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear([Date])-(Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7))`

The problem is that the generated week number has one digit, and I would like to have two digits week number format.
For example: 01, 02, 03 ... etc.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your answer like

= Text.PadStart( Text.From( [ISO Week Number] ), 2, "0" )

such as your original formula

```
#"Inserted ISO Week Number" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ISO Week Number", each Text.PadStart( Text.From(if Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear([Date])-(Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7)=0 then  Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear(#date(Date.Year([Date])-1,12,31))-(Date.DayOfWeek(#date(Date.Year([Date])-1,12,31), Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7) else if (Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear([Date])-(Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7)=53 and (Date.DayOfWeek(#date(Date.Year([Date]),12,31), Day.Monday)+1<4)) then 1 else  Number.RoundDown((Date.DayOfYear([Date])-(Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Monday)+1)+10)/7) ), 2, "0" ))
```

or more compactly

```
#"Inserted ISO Week Number" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ISO Week Number", each Text.PadStart( Text.From(Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod(Number.Mod(28*Number.Mod(Number.IntegerDivide((Number.From([Date]) + 692501) / 7, 1),20871 ) + 4383,146096),1461)/28,1)+1 ), 2, "0" ))
```

or using a function

```
#"Inserted ISO Week Number" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "ISO Week Number", each iso([Date]))
```

with the function

```
(theDate as date) =>
// http://gorilla.bi/power-query/create-iso-week-and-iso-year/ Rick Rothstein
let IWN =  Text.PadStart( Text.From(Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod(Number.Mod(28*Number.Mod(Number.IntegerDivide((Number.From(theDate) + 692501) / 7, 1),20871 ) + 4383,146096),1461)/28,1)+1 ), 2, "0" ) in  IWN
```

[image]

Note this will convert your numeric week to a text field

Comment: Works like a charm! I much appreciate your support.